# Change notification in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I was studying MVC architecture, I learn that when the model is updated all Views (such all open form or view) are informed and given a chance to update themselves (It's a feature of mvc architecture). How can I do this in Asp.Net MVC 3 without ajax?

Thanks if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Without AJAX you post the server and it returns the whole page. In the moment you call the `View()` method in your `Controller`, you let the view render itself with the updated model, so it works as you expect.